# React Is it good way to use classnames for managing multiple themes?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, class-names

Consider the following code:-

```
  render() {
      const headerClasses=classnames({
        "Header":true,
        "Header---dark":this.props.theme.dark,
        "Header--light":this.props.theme.light
      })
    return (
      <div className={headerClasses}>
            Header content goes here
      </div>
    )
  }
```

My application is going to have only two themes. one dark and one light. I am trying to store the theme in redux store and changing the classnames accordingly using classnames. Is it a valid approach or an anti-pattern?. What is the easiest way to manage theme in larger application?

Comment: Arguably the easiest way would be to set a single class on the `body` element (e.g. `theme-light`). Based on that, you can then change all your styles within CSS only. Your approach seems to be very repetitive as you would have to add that everywhere.

Comment: I would check out Styled Components. It has support for multiple themes

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a state attribute with theme, and all corresponding data
2. Set the theme of your components to `this.props.currentTheme`
3. When you change the theme, you're just changing the data in `currentTheme` and all else will change too